# Insertion sort time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

The unusual Θ(n2) implementation of Insertion Sort to sort an array uses linear search to identify the position where an element is to be inserted into the already sorted part of the array. If then, instead, we use binary search to identify the position, the worst case running time will then

**A) remain Θ(n2)**

**B) become Θ(n(logn)2)**

**C) become Θ(nlogn)**

**D) become Θ(n)**

---

This is my first question on stackoverflow please forgive any mistakes.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with quicksort.

Comment: What do **YOU** think and why?

Comment: @MrSmith42 regarding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the question is about Insertion Sort not Quicksort as you display above.

The correct answer is A-Remain Θ(n^2) since even if you can binary search the position of the element in the already sorted part of the array you have to move every element greater than it one position to the right which cause an Θ(k) amount of moves if the original array's element ordering is from greatest to lowest, where k is the initial index of the element being added to the sorted part. The total running time is Θ(n^2) when you do the math.

Question answer aside: the time complexity average case of Randomized-QuickSort is O(nlogn) and it can be proved if you have a mathematical background in expected value (probabilities). You can find more about it reading the quicksort section in the book Introduction to Algorithms (Cormen).

Comment: thankyou so much and please pardon me for the mistake.